# Intersect with Target

Tags: vba, excel

I cannot figure out how to make the code below work.  Every call results in Intersection = Nothing and the ELSE statement selected and yes rngIntersect is valid and non-empty and the intersection is not empty so the problem is with the target part.

When I debug the code and ask ? target the result is zilch.  However target.column, target.row, and target.address are all correct 3,9, and $C$9 respectively).

This must be something basic but after all the looking around on different sites I have yet to come up with a solution.

I can find if the target is within range by using target.column and target.row but I cannot make the more elegant code below work. For whatever reason target seems to be 'somewhat but not completely empty'.

To emphasize, in the debug window ? target returns empty but ? target.address returns $C$9 as it should because that is the cell the user has selected and rngIntersect = $C$9:$N$9, hence Intersect = $C$9 definitely <> Nothing.

I have tried ? range(target) and  ? target.range but that generates an error.

**In essence, how do I make target return the range as it is supposed to, after all it is defined as a range to begin with right?**

```
Sub OnSelectionChange(ByVal target As Range, wksChange As Worksheet)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim rngIntersect As Range, rngTarget As Range

Set rngIntersect = wksChange.Range("RNGINTERSECT")
Set rngTarget = target

    If Not Application.Intersect(rngTarget, rngIntersect) Is Nothing Then
        Call WorksheetSelectionChange(target.Column, wksChange)
    Else
        Call MAIN.ZoomAdjust(wksChange, False)
    End If

ErrorExit:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, C_MODULE, "OnSelectionChange")
    Resume ErrorExit

End Sub
```

Comment: why aren't you using a private Worksheet_SelectionChange or Workbook_SheetSelectionChange?

Comment: What sheet is `target` on?  FWIW `? target` is doing `?target.Value` if `target` is a `Range` - so what is the value in cell C9 of the sheet that `target` is on?  Perhaps execute `?target.Worksheet.Name` if you aren't sure which worksheet you are referring to.

Comment: Do you need two parameters here?  You have `target` and also the parent worksheet, but as @YowE3K points out that's the same as `target.Worksheet` (or `target.Parent`).  Not your core issue here, but you could simplify your method calls a bit...

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem isn't from your code but from your expectation, to wit that `? Target` should print something. `Target` is a range, and when you don't specify which property you want to print the default property will be printed which is `.Value`. The fact that the cell may be empty says nothing about the existence of it as a range object.

`Target` is a range object. Therefore you don't need to convert it into a range object, like rngTarget. As a range object, one of its properties is `.Worksheet` which, therefore, you don't need to pass along as an additional argument. Bear I mind that `Application.Intersect` also returns a range object.

Below is working code. I have stripped out anything that might confuse you, your error handlers in particular. If this kind of code ever creates an error you want to know about it immediately and not only after 3 hours of futile search.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TestIntersect()
    OnSelectionChange Range("C9")
    OnSelectionChange Range("C3")
End Sub

Sub OnSelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim WksChange As Worksheet
    Dim RngIntersect As Range

    Set WksChange = Target.Worksheet
'    Set RngIntersect = WksChange.Range("RNGINTERSECT")
    Set RngIntersect = WksChange.Range("C9:N9")

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, RngIntersect) Is Nothing Then
        WorksheetSelectionChange Target.Column, WksChange
    Else
        MAINZoomAdjust WksChange, False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub WorksheetSelectionChange(ByVal C As Long, _
                                     Ws As Worksheet)
    MsgBox "Here is WorksheetSelectionChange" & vbCr & _
           "Column " & C
End Sub

Private Sub MAINZoomAdjust(Ws As Worksheet, _
                           ByVal TooBig As Boolean)
    MsgBox "Here is MAINZoomAdjust" & vbCr & _
           "TooBig = " & TooBig
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and providing the code.  I just found out what my problem was. wksChange.Range("RNGINTERSECT") does not return the range that I need but the string representation of the range I need.  The correct code is If Not Application.Intersect(target, wksChange.Range(wksChange.Range("RNGINTERSECT"))) Is Nothing Then

Answer (score 0):

I did find the problem. The correct code should be

```vb
If Not Application.Intersect(target, wksChange.Range(wksChange.Range("RNGINTERSECT"))) Is Nothing Then
```

instead of

```vb
If Not Application.Intersect(target, wksChange.Range("RNGINTERSECT")) Is Nothing Then
```

The reason is that `wksChange.Range("RNGINTERSECT")` returns the string value for the range of interest, not the range itself

Comment: Unless you are saying that, in your data, the cell with a range name of "RNGINTERSECT" contains a value which is another range name (even if that next range name is something like "$B$10") then this answer is wrong.  And, if you are saying that that is the situation, then the question should be closed or deleted as there is no way anyone can possibly determine that that is the situation based on the question, and the question will be of no use to anyone else who stumbles across it while searching for answers.

Comment: @YowE3K The code works, I guess I cannot argue with success can I? RNGINTERSECT is a named variable referring to cell Y3 in the sheet ActionLog (called as wksChange in my code). The value of Y3 is $C$9:$N$9 the range I need for the intersection. Hence wksChange.Range(wksChange.Range("RNGINTERSECT")) points to the desired range.

Comment: OK - so you do have a range name in the cell referred to by `wksChange.Range("RNGINTERSECT")`.  FWIW - you should really say `If Not Application.Intersect(target, wksChange.Range(wksChange.Range("RNGINTERSECT").Value)) Is Nothing`.  Using the `.Value` property explicitly when you are referring to the `Value` of a `Range`, rather than just defaulting to using it, will cause you less problems in the future as it will make your code easier to understand.

Comment: I would still suggest that you update the question - your statement in the question that "rngIntersect = $C$9:$N$9" is wrong.  If you had stated in the question that "rngIntersect" was cell Y3 then people would have had a chance to answer.